# Behaviour of display links in views

Tags: views, comments

I have defined a new content type with comments. When I create a new view (page) consisting of the x most recent posts of this content type I see this:

- I choose: Show content | Teasers + display links. I get an overview page consisting of teasers and each teaser has the Add new comment link (as well as the Read More link). This I understand.
- I choose: Show content | Full content + display links. I get an overview page consisting of full content and only nodes with comments have the Add new comment link. This I do not understand. Why is the Add new comment link not visible for each node? And how can I make it visible (in node.tpl.php?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding comments in Full content view mode happens, not through a link, but in the comment form that is displayed below the node (assuming it is set to be displayed in the content type's comment settings), but you need to switch on the Display comments checkbox in the Page: Row style options dialog.

You're right, Display links will print the add comment link in Teaser mode. If you have Full content mode and have both Display links and Display comments on, then you get both the link AND the form, which is akward. I don't know why it is that way.

Comment: Thanks Kari. I found this link which explains my problem exactly: https://drupal.org/node/1490680. It seems this is (very strange) standard behaviour.